# navigation back button method

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I'm working with an iOS application and I want to artificially induce the action of the "back" button in a navigation bar through other events or button presses. Is this possible, and if so what methods are there to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using a navigation controller and that it's functionality is what you want to emulate. In that case, you can directly access it (every view controller has a link to its navigation controller) and ask it to pop the current view controller from the top of the stack:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: not sure why anybody voted this down, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @0x7fffffff, I've added some more as I am making some assumptions, thanks.